# Laravel, Can't update a soft-deleted value

Tags: laravel, validation, soft-delete

I have this values in my db:

```
id - name - created_at - updated_at - deleted_at
------------------------------------------------
1  - John - 2018-11-11 - 2018-11-11 -  (NULL)
2  - John - 2018-11-11 - 2018-11-11 -  2018-11-11
```

If I search for "John" with my Datatable (Yajra) I only see the John with `id=1` because I'm using softdeletes. My model is this:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

When I delete (destroy) a registry it puts a date at `deleted_at` which is correct. But when I want to edit (update) `John` the Validator is giving me the error that that value is already in use. My update method is this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'unique:my_table'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        MyModel::find($id)->update($request->input());
        return redirect()->route('myroute')->withFlashSuccess('Ok!');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the `SoftDeletes`, it is a validation issue. The `unique` validation rule is very special, because in case of an update it needs to know which entry it may ignore when performing the validation. In the background, the rule is performing an SQL query like

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT id
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  name = 'some value'
) 
    SELECT  1
ELSE 
    SELECT  0
```

(it may not be the exact query, but similar).

As you can see, the query does not take into account if you perform an update or not. Because your entity already exists, it will return `1` and therefore fail the validation because it thinks that the value under validation is not unique.

But there is actually a way to make the validation work for updates. You simply have to add the `id` of the existing entity (which is being validated) as third parameter to the validation rule. So your rules should look something like this:

```
$rules = [
    'name' => 'unique:my_table,name,'.$id
];
```

Please be aware that there is also a second parameter for the `unique` validation rule - the column of the database table you want to search in.

---

**Edit:**

In case the unique constraint does only relate to *not deleted* entries, meaning that a unique value may be reused if other occurences of the same value are flagged as deleted, then it may be necessary to add an additional `where()` clause to the `unique` validation rule. For this, the fourth parameter needs to be set to the `identifier` column name and then we can add the additional `where` clauses as pairs of two parameters.

```
$rules = [
    'name' => 'unique:my_table,name,'.$id.',id,deleted_at,NULL'
];
```

This will add `where('deleted_at', 'NULL')` (or `whereNull('deleted_at')`) to the query.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. About the 2nd parameter, in documentation of Laravel says `The field under validation must be unique in a given database table. If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used.` that's what I'm using as field name, same than the DB, to avoid to use a 2nd parameter (same in blade, the same field name, input and column name). Now, I'm giving the $id as 3rd parameter but it still saying that that value is already in use.

Comment: Hmm, I did what the other answer says in the link. The line of the rule array is this now: `'name' => "unique:the_table,name,{$id},id,deleted_at,NULL",` and voila, it works. It's the same what you said, using the id but in this case I don't get why I have to use the others parameters...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I didn't pay enough attention to your requirement that names can be reused, but only when all other entities with the same name are deleted. In this case you obviously only check for uniqueness on not yet deleted entries. I edited my answer to add your solution for other users with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

This person has written a blog post that looks like it would solve your problem:

https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/laravel-soft-delete-unique-validations/

I'm not 100% sure you want to do this though as you may later wish to use the restore() method to bring the soft-deleted data back. At which point, you'll have a collision.

Comment: Good content there in the link! But you should add the important part to your answer because links may become broken over time and then your answer is basically gone.