# how to update soft deleted value from table in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, soft-delete

as i have already done the step which is mentioned in this link.[Laravel, Can't update a soft-deleted value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184868/laravel-cant-update-a-soft-deleted-value)..
please help

Comment: just set it to `null`

Comment: i already did..but nothing happend

Comment: please check and share your model class

Comment: thank you so much @phpdroid for your time...i just solved the problem..i correct the table name..and problem solved -:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using withTashed() when you fetch the data to edit.

```
// suppose user with id 2 is soft deleted.
eg: User::find(2) // this will return null and you won't be able to update the user
```

## To fetch the soft deleted user, you should use withTrashed()

```
eg: User::withTrashed()->find(2)->update(['deleted_at' => null);
Or User::withTrashed()->find(2)->restore();
```

ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7#soft-deleting

Comment: update() was not working in but restore() worked!